# Does this Ruby method correctly use symbols?

Tags: ruby, methods, symbols

I'm working on a code challenge and I am stuck.

What do each of these methods do and what value does each of them return?

```
def format_name(name) 
  return "#{name[:last]}, #{name[:first]}"
end

def display_name(name)
  puts format_name(name)
end
```

Comment: displays `lastname, firstname`

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what `name` is, but assuming it's a hash like

```
`{ :first => "Joe", :last => "Smith" }`
```

it prints "Smith, Joe".

You can read the [Hash documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html) to learn more about how Hashes work.

Answer (score 0):

The first method returns a string. The `return` keyword is redundant here.

`puts`, in the second method, sends the string to STDOUT and returns nil.